# I made UITextField subclass. when I select keyboard, occur EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, uitextfield, exc-bad-access

I made this.

header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef BOOL (^validationType)(UITextField *textField);

@interface GLPValidationTextField : UITextField<UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (copy, nonatomic) validationType validation;

@end
```

body

```
#import "GLPValidationTextField.h"

@implementation GLPValidationTextField

@synthesize validation;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)inCoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:inCoder]) {
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}



#pragma - mark UITextField delegate

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    return validation(textField);
}
```

and, set This TextField with IB.

and, use this

```
[self.mailTextField setValidation:validationBlock];
```

**this is work.**

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    return validation(textField);
}
```

this method called. I can validation.

but, when I select keyboard with the button like globe(change English Keyboard to Japanese Keyboard or something),
occur EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Simulator.

Enable Zombies, but console show nothing.

What's happen? when I select keyboard. why did occur EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

when occur EXC_BAD_ACCESS always Xcode show

```
libobjc.A.dylib`lookUpMethod:
0x1647a9a:  pushl  %ebp
0x1647a9b:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x1647a9d:  pushl  %ebx
0x1647a9e:  pushl  %edi
0x1647a9f:  pushl  %esi
0x1647aa0:  subl   $28, %esp
0x1647aa3:  calll  0x1647aa8                 ; lookUpMethod + 14 // Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Comment: Bad access can happen when you try to use an object that has been released. If you enable zombies, you should be able to see what kind of object it's failing on.
To enable zombies, go to edit scheme and in the last tab (diagnostics) tick the `Enable Zombie Objects` box

Comment: Check that your validation block != nil.

Comment: Enable Zombies and then track with proper reason of crash.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: No. I gave up to make subclass.